# How to set select options using firebase database and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database (.JSON):

```
{
  "permissionLevels" : {
    "Admin" : {
      "Comment Access" : "value",
      "Page Access" : "value",
      "Post Access" : "value"
    },
    "Default" : {
      "Comment Access" : "value",
      "Page Access" : "value",
      "Post Access" : "value"
    },
    "Template" : {
      "Comment Access" : "value",
      "Page Access" : "value",
      "Post Access" : "value"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "User 1" : {
      "Email" : "user1@gmail.com",
      "Name" : "User 1",
      "PhotoURL" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-m1_AWD2hhp0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZY/IhIwoLVwl6U/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "Role" : "Default",
      "uid" : "1235"
    },
    "User 2" : {
      "Email" : "user2@gmail.com",
      "Name" : "User 2",
      "Role" : "Default",
      "uid" : "1236"
    },
    "User 3" : {
      "Email" : "user3@gmail.com",
      "Name" : "User 3",
      "PhotoURL" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-m1_AWD2hhp0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZY/IhIwoLVwl6U/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "Role" : "Admin",
      "uid" : "1237"
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Permission Level</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in users">
    <td>{{value.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{value.Email}}</td>
    <td>
      <select name="{{key}}">
        <option ng-model="key">{{value.Role}}</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(permissionLevel, permissions) in permissionLevels.permissionLevels" ng-if="permissionLevel!=value.Role && permissionLevel!='Template'" ng-selected="string">{{permissionLevel}}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><br/>
```

What I want to do is display a table with each user's name, email and role (permission level). The role for each person should be displayed in a `<select></select>` tag and the user should be able to change it and click "UPDATE ALL" to save changes. I got the table to display everything properly but, the issue is getting information out of the table and onto the database. This is what I have so far on the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr3Ag.png)

In case you are wondering, I want it to ignore the "Template" role because it is there to use as a template for later on.

Comment: So does your problem relies in trying to save the changes you make in the data you are currently displaying? What have u tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject` have 3-way data binding. The view, controller, and database.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
// var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/users");
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

When you click "Update" you need to iterate through and `$save` all the records that changed roles.

First I would change your `select` to:

```
<select name="{{key}}" ng-options="p.value as p.label for p in permissionLevels" ng-model="value.Role">
</select>
```

Assuming you have an array of roles:

```
$scope.permissionLevels = [
    {
        value: "Default",
        label: "Default",   
    },
    {
        value: "Admin",
        label: "Admin",   
    }
];
```

Then when clicking "Update" you can call some function:

```
$scope.update = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.users.length; i++) {
        // Saves all
        $scope.users.$save(i).then(function(ref) {
            // whatever
        })
    }
}
```

Reference: [$firebaseArray $save](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-saverecordorindex)